# RegisterPreviousData on Uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My installer is using RegisterPreviousData to remember user selection (common/full installation), and i want to use it in custom uninstall form (with same selection - full/common uninstall). But will it work for uninstall? When it is actually called?

Comment: Uninstaller is in most cases used to clean everything that's been saved in the user's system. This includes also the data registered by this method. So even if that would work, the data would be deleted right after. If you want to save some user data in more persistent way, use a different way, e.g. dedicated registry node (that won't be deleted by uninstaller), or some file (somewhere where won't be touched by the uninstaller).

Comment: Too bad if it works this way. Well, it seems i don't need it anyway.

Comment: The purpose of that thing is to remember custom data as long as the application is installed (they can be re-used by the same installer, or in uninstaller).